# Tridion Sites 9.6 - Poolparty setup - PoolParty Taxonomies not being indexed

Tags: sites-9.6

I was working on the Tridion Sites 9.6 PoolParty Integration for the headless implementation.

In the Tridion Sites 9.6, I was able to get it working PoolParty connectors for the Taxonomies ON CM side. And then tried to publish to DXD using data-template-less publishing. but my publishing got failed on the deployer side, spent quite some research and found the issue. Just sharing this knowledge with other community users.

**Publishing queue error message:**

```
Deploying Failed - Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. Unable to process ES indexing.
```

**Here are the deployer logs:**

`2022-12-15 09:36:51,435 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] TcmModelIndexer - All indexing operations failed. Please review the failed operations in iq-indexing-error.log 2022-12-15 09:36:51,435 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] TcmModelIndexer - Failing publish transaction completely, as we're configured to do so. 2022-12-15 09:36:51,435 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] TridionSearchIndexDeployStep - Unable to process ES indexing. com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionContentDataException: All indexing operations failed. Please review the failed operations in iq-indexing-error.log at com.tridion.deployer.modules.index.TcmModelIndexer.processIndexOperationResponses(TcmModelIndexer.java:286) at com.tridion.deployer.modules.index.TcmModelIndexer.index(TcmModelIndexer.java:224) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionSearchIndexDeployStep.process(TridionSearchIndexDeployStep.java:194) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:73) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:58) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:41) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 2022-12-15 09:36:51,653 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] DefaultIndexingClient -  com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.http.ApiException:  at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.http.ApiClient.handleUnsuccessfulResponse(ApiClient.java:1035) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.http.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:993) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.http.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:907) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.http.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:890) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.api.IndexApi.createOrReplaceUsingPUT(IndexApi.java:203) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.DefaultIndexingClient.lambda$sendToIndex$1(DefaultIndexingClient.java:75) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.DefaultIndexingClient.performSendToIndex(DefaultIndexingClient.java:170) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.DefaultIndexingClient.sendToIndex(DefaultIndexingClient.java:74) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.client.DefaultIndexer.sendToIndex(DefaultIndexer.java:60) at com.tridion.deployer.modules.index.TcmModelIndexer.index(TcmModelIndexer.java:222) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionSearchIndexDeployStep.process(TridionSearchIndexDeployStep.java:194) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:73) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:58) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:41) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537) at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

**IQ Index service logs:**

`2022-12-15 09:36:51,341 ERROR [http-nio2-8097-exec-9] DocumentController - Couldn't perform create/update request. com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.api.provider.IndexProviderException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/udp-index/_doc/tcm_5-373], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"analyzer [analyzer_pparty1] has not been configured in mappings"}},"status":400} at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.ElasticSearchIndexProvider.handleResponseExceptionForCreate(ElasticSearchIndexProvider.java:534) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.ElasticSearchIndexProvider.lambda$documentCreateOrUpdate$0(ElasticSearchIndexProvider.java:165) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.api.DefaultDocumentApi.handleResponseException(DefaultDocumentApi.java:147) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.api.DefaultDocumentApi.access$100(DefaultDocumentApi.java:37) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.api.DefaultDocumentApi$HandlingHelper.process(DefaultDocumentApi.java:133) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.api.DefaultDocumentApi.createOrUpdate(DefaultDocumentApi.java:73) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.ElasticSearchIndexProvider.documentCreateOrUpdate(ElasticSearchIndexProvider.java:168) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.controller.v1.DocumentController.createOrUpdate(DocumentController.java:169) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.controller.common.IqTraceLoggingInterceptor.doFilter(IqTraceLoggingInterceptor.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at com.sdl.web.readwrite.filter.ReadWriteFilter.doFilter(ReadWriteFilter.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:301) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1685) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1167) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:613) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:591) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/udp-index/_doc/tcm_5-373], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"analyzer [analyzer_pparty1] has not been configured in mappings"}},"status":400} at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:326) at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296) at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270) at com.sdl.delivery.iq.index.provider.elastic.api.DefaultDocumentApi$HandlingHelper.process(DefaultDocumentApi.java:131) ... 96 common frames omitted`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, I missed uploading the **deployer-taxonomy** add-on package to the add-on service, add-on package can be found in this location on the Installation media. after uploading the package to the add-on service and restarting the deployer then my publishing worked fine.

- \TridionSites9.6\Content Delivery\roles\deployer\add-ons\udp-deployer-taxonomy-extension-assembly-11.6.0-1374-search-config.json
- \TridionSites9.6\Content Delivery\roles\deployer\add-ons\udp-deployer-taxonomy-extension-assembly-11.6.0-1374-search-config.json

**Troubleshooting background:**

If you find your item eg Component or Page is failing to publish when it contains a Pool Party concept, it is most likely that there is something wrong with your setup.

When looking in the IQ indexer logs you see something like:-

`analyzer {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"analyzer [analyzer_cocktails] has not been configured in mappings"}},"status":400}`

When publishing a Component that contains a Concept scheme that is not in your concept index, this scheme should be automatically indexed by the Deployer, using the JSON config passed to the Connector extension.

1. **Check that Deployer connectors folder**

If there is something wrong with your setup, then you will be missing the PoolParty connector in deployer\standalone\connectors folder eg what you should be seeing:-

[image]

Look for  PoolParty Connector-Connector-....... If it's not there, there is something wrong with your setup.

1. **Check your are passing the CD environment type to your service (staging/live)**
2. Check the Pool party connector and deployer-taxonomy add-on packages are added and updated configurations as expected.
   [image]

I hope it helps.